# Image Hovers are not working - what is wrong with the code?

Tags: html, css

It seems as though I have tried everything I can think of to get these image links to change images when hovering over. Right now only the main navprint.png is showing up. I am a beginner as far as html and css and have struggled with this issue for days. Here is the code. Any help would be really appreciated.

html

```
<li class="navprint"><a href="printcategory.html"><img src="Images/navprint.png"      alt="print button" title="print button"></a></li>
```

css

```
.navprint {
    width: 160px;
    height: 30px;
    background-image: url("Images/navprint.png");
}

.navprint:hover {
    background-image: url('Images/navprinthov.jpg');
    width: 160px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: your code works fine ..see this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2pSF/)

Comment: it works in my FF 18. BTW: You can leave the `width: 160px;`and `height: 30px;` away in `.navprint:hover`, because You defined it already in the `.navprint`... :))

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<li class="navprint">
 <a href="printcategory.html">
   <img src="Images/navprint.png" alt="print button" title="print button" />
 </a>
</li>


.navprint {
    width: 160px;
    height: 30px;
    background-image: url("Images/navprint.png");
}

.navprint:hover {
    background-image: url('Images/navprinthov.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Actually made the PNG transparent and then just added a background color to the hover. that worked. decided against using a rollover image because it was too complicated to work.

Comment: the hover must work unless the path of the image is not right